# Linq.Dynamic Select custom column with operation

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I use LINQ Dynamic Query Library
https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library
It works great for querying to query fields optionally

```
  IQueryable GetSource( DataTable t, String str)
        {
    //Working str = "new (T[\"ss\"] as ss,T[\"xx\"] as xx )"
   //Not Working str = "new (T[\"ss\"] as ss, T[\"xx\"] as xx , T[\"ss\"] +T[\"xx\"] as yy)"
           return (from T in t.AsEnumerable()
                   select new{T}).AsQueryable().Select(str);  
        }
```

But when I try to
Operations such as (addition - multiplication - division - merge)
gets wrong
How can I do the accounting operations and merge fields

Comment: What does "gets wrong" mean? The actual error message or invalid value description would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `DataRow` `item` property to get the value for a field. This method returns an `object` which you can't add. You need to cast to the proper type.

```
"new (T[\"ss\"] as ss, T[\"xx\"] as xx, int(T[\"ss\"])+int(T[\"xx\"]) as yy)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
Indeed, it must be converted because it is the object

```
 IQueryable GetSource( DataTable t, String str)
        {
    //Working str = "new (T[\"ss\"] as ss,T[\"xx\"] as xx )"
   //Working str = "new (T[\"ss\"] as ss,T[\"xx\"] as xx , string.Concat(T[\"ss\"], T[\"xx\"])  as yy  )"
  //Working str = ""new (T[\"ss\"] as ss,T[\"xx\"] as xx , decimal(T[\"ss\"]) + decimal(T[\"xx\"])  as yy  )""

           return (from T in t.AsEnumerable()
                   select new{T}).AsQueryable().Select(str);  
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).